# How to combine the KeyUpHandler and the ValueChangeHandler in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, handlers

I found that the KeyUpHandler seems to be the most dynamic Handler for a TextBox if I want instant update after entering something. However considering that the values might change without somebody pressing a key gives the need to use a ValueChangeHandler, which unfortunately when used alone isn't as dynamic and isn't triggered everytime you change the contents of the TextBox with the keyboard.

Right now I have a method like this to add both handlers to the TextBox, but I guess it's not the best way to add multiple handlers like that and probably not very performant either:

```
private void addInputValueChangeHandlers(TextBox inputTextBox) {
    inputTextBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            updateResult();
        }
    });

    inputTextBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            updateResult();
        }
    });
}
```

So is there a way to combine them or a handler that would give the same effect as this one?

Answer (score 0):

Override onBrowseEvent or use NativePreview Handler to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should detect yourself if something has changed in the `onKeyUp` method by doing something like:

```
private void addInputValueChangeHandlers(TextBox inputTextBox) {
    inputTextBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            if(!inputTextBox.getValue().equals(previousValue)){
               updateResult();
             }
            previousValue = inputTextBox.getValue();
        }
    });
}
```

Where `previousValue` is an attribute of your class whose initial value equals to `null`.

Comment: Yeah, but if the value in the TextBox would get changed without someone using keys, it wouldn't be called I guess. And that's exactly the reason why I am putting both handlers on the TextBox